# Using hash in node definition and passing to template

Tags: hash, puppet

I'm struggling to get this to work and don't understand where I'm going wrong, can someone please guide me on how to correct?

Basically I want to get an array in my nodes.pp, which is then used by my templates file by cycling through it and writing a line of each element:

```
nodes.pp:
    node test{
        net::addr { 'routing':
          $routes = {
            route1 => {
                address => '172.29.54.70',
                netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                gateway => '172.29.54.65',
                dev     => 'eth0',
            },
            route2 => {
                address => '192.168.1.3',
                netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                gateway => '192.168.1.1',
                dev     => 'eth3',
            },
          }
        }
}
```

When I run the puppet client i keep getting the following:

err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '='; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/
test.pp:3 on node test.myincorp.net

addr.pp

```
define net::addr (
  $address='',
  $netmask='',
  $gateway='',
  $dev='',
) {

  file { "route-${name}":
    ensure  => 'present',
    mode    => '0644',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    path    => "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-${name}",
    content => template('network/addr.erb'),
}
}
```

Template: addr.erb:

```
<% routes.each do |route| -%>
  <%= route['address'] %>  <%= route['netmask'] %> <%= route['gateway'] %> <%= route['dev'] %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Can someone help me with fixing the above please?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual issue here is the use of a variable (`$routes`) in the definition of a resource: instead of using a `$routes = { ... }`, you must set key/value pairs in the definition of a resource, such as `routes => { ... }`.

But I actually would recommend a different route entirely: have you seen the [puppet-network](https://github.com/razorsedge/puppet-network) module? It handles creation of static route files for you automatically, so you wouldn't have to implement any of this functionality yourself. For example, puppet-network implements this using the following:

```
network::route { "eth0":
  address => [ "192.168.2.0", "10.0.0.0", ],
  netmask => [ "255.255.255.0", "255.0.0.0", ],
  gateway => [ "192.168.1.1", "10.0.0.1", ],
}
```

See more details at [GitHub](https://github.com/razorsedge/puppet-network) or [PuppetForge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/razorsedge/network)